# Implementing "silktide cookie consent with new google Asynchronous analytics snippet

Tags: javascript, cookies, asynchronous, google-analytics

Hello I need some help on how to apply the silk tide cookie consent script http://silktide.com/cookieconsent/code. (I want to ad this due to the EU cookie law etc). Now The only thing I am aware of which uses cookies on my site is Google Analytics, but the code example given on the cookie consent code page is for the old Google Analytics snippet, not the new Asynchronous snippet. As my javascript skills arent that great I am not fully sure how to apply the cookie consent to the Google Analytics Asynchronous snippet as per "step 5. Modify your site" on the silktide cookie consent code page. Hope someone can help :)
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your new Google Analytics snippet starts with

```
<script>
```

Simply change this to

```
<script type="text/plain" class="cc-onconsent-analytics">
```

see: http://sitebeam.net/cookieconsent-v1/documentation/code-examples/#examples-advertising